# write an adapter that maps all the LinkedSetFx events to the expected Flex collection events(As3Common-collection)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, collections

`LinkeSetFx` has its own CollectionEvent, but I don't know how to map the `LinkedSetFx event` to `mx.events.collectionEvent`(I want use it in ComboBox). LinkedSetFx is in AS3Commons-collection framework.Here is the [url](http://code.google.com/p/as3-commons/downloads/list), choose the as3commons-collections-1.0.0.zip, you'll find LinkedSetFx in src\org\as3commons\collections\fx

Comment: I think you're headed down the wrong path.  The reason why things are more difficult than they ought to be is because you're trying to jam a square peg into a round hole.  Specifically, you say you selected the LinkedSet because you want good performance when adding and removing thousands of unique items.  However, any performance gain is lost 1000x over if you tie every addition and removal to a ComboBox update.

Comment: @Gunslinger47. You mean even if I use LinkedSet as dataProvider in ComboBox, the ComboBox has to iterate the data, so performance is lost?

Comment: Something like that.  Updating a ComboBox (or any UI component) is not a high performance operation.  Typically what you'd want to do is keep your underlying data structure fast, while updating your UI infrequently or where appropriate.  The ideal solution depends on what these thousands of items are and why your user needs to select one.  I suspect that either the ComboBox doesn't need to be *perfectly* up to date, or something other than a ComboBox is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Ueq88nAe-j0/trunk/as3-commons-collections/src/main/examples/LinkedSetFxExample.as&q=LinkedSetFx%20package:http://as3-commons%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc&d=4) from package.

```
 var theSet : LinkedSetFx = new LinkedSetFx();
 theSet.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGED, changedHandler);
```

Is this you looked for?

Comment: Here the CollectionEvent is not mx.events.collectionEvent, but the framework event

Comment: can't you just add an event handler which listens for the framework event and dispatch the mx.events.collectionEvent on `theSet`?

Comment: better post somewhere your project, so we could try to hack it in that way you want :)

Comment: I will post my project to a new question named "LinkedSet use in ComboBox issue"